# Memory error in Python for loops

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm currently trying to find the largest prime number contained within another large number.

```
maxlen = 1024
for i in range(1023, -1, -1):
    maxlen -= 1
    number = ""
    for k in range(maxlen, -1, -1):
            number = pi[k] + number
            if isprime(number) == True:
                    print number
```

isprime() is a function that checks if the number is a prime (pretty standard).
this works pretty well up to a certain point where I get a MemoryError.

This is not because the number checked by the function is too large since it happens around the 6th run of the first for loop.

I've already tried gc.enable() and gc.collect() without any positive result.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Edit: definition of pi and isprime() as per request:

```
f = open("/root/number", "r")
pi = f.read()
f.close()
```

where the file "number" contains the original number in which I'd like to find the prime.

```
def isprime(n):
    n = abs(int(n))
    if n < 2:
            return False
    if n == 2:
            return True
    if not n & 1:
            return False
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
            if n % x == 0:
                    return False
    return True
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./primal.py", line 36, in <module>
    if isprime(number) == True:
  File "./primal.py", line 24, in isprime
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
MemoryError
```

Comment: What is the definition of `isprime`?

Comment: Also, could you provide the traceback output?

Comment: What is `pi`? And why aren't you just using `for maxlen in range(1023, -1, -1):`?

Comment: And copy us the error line, if I recall Python gives you some details to find out at which line the error occurred. By the way, you don't need the "== True" part of the if statement.

Comment: @Edol: That's the traceback, requested by nadirs. :-)

Comment: Oh well, I at least _emphasized_ the need for the traceback :D

Comment: Sorry for being so incomplete. Post has been edited to provide more information.

Comment: Building strings is also quite expensive and unnecessary in your case.  Instead of `number = ""` and `number = pi[k] + number`, do the math with integers: `number = 0` and `number = (number * 10) + int(pi[k])`.  Then, you can also drop the `int(n)` within `is_prime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of `range`, most importantly in `isprime`, here:

```
for x in xrange(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
```

`xrange` doesn't create the whole list in memory, while range does, but you are not using the results after you iterated over them.

Another tip: just test for `isprime(n)`, there is no need to see if it is equal to `True`, that is what `if` *does*. :-)

```
if isprime(number):  # Only works if isprime(number) is boolean True
    ...
```

Comment: Generators and lazy evaluation in general sure are great for memory-intensive stuff.

Comment: great tips, thx. still doesn't work though but I'll keep searching for those errors myself first

Comment: @fragman: remember to use a new SO Question for each new problem you encounter (and search for existing answers).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Since I don't get the MemoryError anymore this seems to be the case. However the program still dies at the exact same point as before...

Comment: @fragman: presumably with a different error now; which is a *new* problem. :-)

Comment: Rather without any error. It's just stalling basically. But you're right, this would be a new problem :)

Answer (score 4):

If this is in Python v **2.x** use `xrange()` instead of `range()`.
`range()` generates a list all at once in memory,  while `xrange()` works "on-demand", generating a value each time you need one.

In Python **3.x** `xrange()` is gone, and `range()` acts like `xrange()` used to.

To quote from [What's New in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> range() now behaves like xrange() used to behave, except it works with
>   values of arbitrary size. The latter no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I'm still using 2.7, so I changed it to xrange(), but I'll keep that in mind when I switch to 3.x

Comment: @fragman You are welcome. I recently started to use v3 (in addition to continue to use 2.7) and found the "What's New .. in 3" an interesting/informative read.